# Dns NS on windows server 2008

Tags: iis-7, dns, windows-server-2008

I want to use my winserver 2008 to host my own pages. I got a couple of domains. So I want to setup my server to it.

Now to the questions and thoughts.

1.Do I create NS1, NS2, NS3 on this one server? If are they done in the _msdcs, or the MYDNS.COM.. NS I mean Name Server, i need atleas 2 to redirect the domain(u knew this but anyway)

2.Do I need different ips for each one of the NS? If how can I setup more ip's I only got one?

3.Do I need to do any more then setting the domain name in the iis7 when I create a web page or does it know how to find it? Like do I need to set that the domain1.com need to go to a specific folder where the files are?

This is just some basic thoughts I wonder about on this topic. If I could just get some leads I am sure I can find info and figure out how to, but I appreciate all help I can get.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a serverfault question than a stackoverflow question

https://serverfault.com/questions/88154/dns-ns-records-vs-a-record

https://serverfault.com/questions/111768/dns-ns-record-question-in-windows-server-2008

Comment: AFAIK there's some way of migrating questions from one site to another - I'm not sure what it is or who can do it, but migrating this one to SF seems like a good choice if possible. :)